# Crystal Reports and Visual Studio 2010 Error: Unsupported Operation

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I Googled for this error, and found many links on SAP as well as StackOverflow, but none of these seem to answer my specific problem.

I have developed a web application using VS 2010, ASP.NET 4.0 and Crystal Reports. I have deployed this application on Windows 2003 R2, Enterprise Edition, SP 2, 32-bit, on IIS 6. I have installed Crystal Report Distributable 32-bit, Version - 13.0.8.1216, on the server. The data source is Oracle 11g XE, on a separate server

When I browse the report from the browser (IE, FF), the reports are visible in the viewer for some time. The problem is after some time, I start getting the following error:

Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack

As suggested in many solutions, i have checked the availability of the report files(.rpt) and they are available on \Reports folder. The aspnet_client folder is also available which has a crystalreportviewer13 folder inside aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319

I have no clue, why it will work perfectly fine initially, but later it will start giving this error. I thinks it is probably when I try to access the application concurrently from 3-4 different machines. I replicated this behaviour once.

Now if restart the server machine, it again works fine. Restarting just IIS does not help

Would appreciate any help, as I am at my wits end to find a solution. I will readily provide any other information if required.

Comment: No response from anyone since last 4 days. Is the question so difficult?